# How can I update a woocommerce product price programmatically in my custom wordpress plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

To begin with I am having problems trying to update a `products price` based on the `products ID` in `woocommerce`. I don't want to use any kind of solution associated with `hooks` like: `save_post` `etc...`

> Woocommerce Version: 3+

To be more exact here is my code and what I am trying to do:

**CODE**:

```
<?php
// I receive 2 $_POST values which I store inside 2 different variables.
$price = $_POST['price'];
$product_id = $_POST['product_id'];

// Then I am trying the code bellow to update the price of the product with `product id` = $product_id.
$product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
if( ! $product->is_on_sale() ){ update_post_meta( $product_id, '_price', $price ); }
update_post_meta( $product_id, '_regular_price', $price );
wc_delete_product_transients( $product_id );
```

**PROBLEM**:

- I am getting this error returned from the php code above:

  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wc_get_product() in /home/something/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-name/folder/this.php:6
  Stack trace:
  #0 {main}
  thrown in /home/something/public_html/wp-content/plugins/my-plugin-name/folder/this.php on line 6

**QUESTIONS**:

- What is wrong about my code above?
- How could I modify this code to achieve what I want?
- How can I define the woocommerce function that is being reported in the error?

*Thanks in advance for your time and effort*!

Comment: As the error suggests wc_get_product() is not defined, i'm inclined to think that Woocommerce is not actually being loaded on that page/template because that should work fine.

Comment: @Adrian , Thank you for the information, I will make sure to check that up and update my question!

Comment: @Adrian , How can I Include woocommerce to make the function be "defined"? Because doing `global woocommerce;` and then doing something like `$product = $woocommerce->wc_get_product( $product_id );` Doesn't seem to work!